# For all real numbers, show that if $f(x)$ is a continuous odd function then $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

First, by definition of odd functions I have  $-f(x) = f (-x)$. It would follow that $|–f(x)|= |f(-x)|$.   Then given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ s.t.  when $0 < |x| < \delta$, it follows that $|f(x)-M| < \epsilon$. With $M = 0$, then $|f(x)| < \epsilon$. (approaching $0$ from the left). If I look at $f (-x)$, assuming identical $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ because of symmetry about the origin, I have the same conclusion that $|f(x)| < \epsilon$. But I feel as though this is too general and I can’t wrap my head around stating it with math fluency that leads to a solid conclusion. Or that I'm even in the correct rabbit hole. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the slight impression you're making your job a bit harder than it seems to be.

First, because our function is continuous, we know that our limit does exist.

Second, I suggest you assume your limit is anything other than zero. Without loss of generality, we can say it could be a $\varepsilon >0$.

Now, what happens if we just move a tiny little bit to either side of zero? Can you say something about $f(-\delta),f(\delta)$? Does that somehow contradict the fact that $f$ is odd?

So, now, what does happen. Let assume that $f(0)=\varepsilon>0$. Then, since we are continuous, we know that there is a $\delta$ such that $|f(\pm\delta)-f(0)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, which tells us that $f(\pm\delta)>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>0$.

Can you take it from there? Keep in mind, we have not yet used that $f$ is odd.

Comment: so proof by contradiction here?

Comment: Yup. In this case, it seemed the most obvious choice to me, unless you already know that $f(0)=0$ for an odd function, in which case your merely need to say "Continuous, yay".

Comment: hmmmmm....scribbling and scribbling...might you be able to set up some fluency for me here

Comment: Added a slightly more detailed explanation - does this help? Not yet done every single step, but maybe you'll be able to work your way through.

Comment: that explains it well. thanks for the example

Answer (score 6):

Since $f$ is odd then $f(0)=0$ and since $f$ is continuous then
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=f(0)=0$$